# Numeric softkeypad appears and instantly changes to normal keypad

Tags: android, input, android-edittext, custom-adapter, numeric-keypad

HI all I was looking for a little help with my numeric softkeypad and an EditText. I have an activity with basically a 2 column table  which has 1 column editable via EditText. I want the numeric phone keypad to appear when an EditText is clicked. It does do this but it almost instantly switches to a normal keypad. Sometimes it switches a couple of times??
The view is inside a custom adapter which is modified code from [this blog](http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2008/04/custom-widget-adapters.html)

There is an xml file for the activity but it isn't really used they are set up programmatically. The xml file contains a linearLayout, ListView and a blank textview and edittext.

```
public class MethodEditor extends ListActivity {

private ArrayList<String[]> thismethod = new ArrayList<String[]>();


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
   super.onCreate(icicle);
   Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras().getBundle("scanparam");
   ArrayList<String> param = new ArrayList<String>();//{
   param = extras.getStringArrayList("PARAM");
   ArrayList<String> value = new ArrayList<String>();
   value = extras.getStringArrayList("VALUE");
      for (int i = 0;  i < length; i++){      
       thismethod.add(new String[]{param.get(i), value.get(i)});
    }
   setContentView(R.layout.method_editor);
   MethodEditorAdapter editorAdapter = new MethodEditorAdapter(this, thismethod ); 
   setListAdapter( editorAdapter );
}
```

Now the custom adapter

```
class MethodAdapterView extends LinearLayout {        
    public MethodAdapterView(Context context, 
            String[] strings ) {
        super( context );

       // this.setOrientation(HORIZONTAL);        
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams Params = 
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        Params.setMargins(1, 1, 1, 1);

        TextView paramname = new TextView( context );
        paramname.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE);
        paramname.setText(strings[0]);
        paramname.setTextSize(20f);
        paramname.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        addView( paramname, Params);       

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams Value = 
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(150, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        Value.setMargins(1, 1, 1, 1);

        EditText paramvalue = new EditText(context);

        paramvalue.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL );
          paramvalue.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE);
          paramvalue.setText(strings[1]);
        paramvalue.setTextSize(20f );
        paramvalue.setTextColor(Color.BLACK); 

        addView( paramvalue, Value); 

    }
```

}

```
public class MethodEditorAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<String[]>  scanparam;

public MethodEditorAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String[]> scanparam ) { 
    this.context = context;
    this.scanparam = scanparam;
}


public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 
    return new MethodAdapterView(this.context, scanparam.get(position) );
}
```

}

This should be straightforward stuff but I presume something is going wrong in the custom adapter.
Any ideas anyone?

I think it is more to do with my phone's default settings of querty keyboard that messes it up. If I manually change the phone settings to phone keypad then it works.
Can I do this automatically?